# How to open database in Client PC and Connect with it?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I created a setup for a management system in Visual Studio and I used a Microsoft SQL Server database file,I installed SQL Server 2017 Express on the client machine and I made Copy of my Database.mdf (gym.mdf) and paste it in client computer's SQLexpress Data
I get this message when I tried to connect to the database. What is the problem?
My connection string to work on client's PC :

```
@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;database=gym";
```

[image]

Comment: Check the logs on the SQL Instance and then post the error from there, that will tell us the *real* connection failure reason.

Comment: Also, *don't* post photos of screens (it's not even a screenshot)... Error messages are text, and should be posted as text, in block quotes. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: A  few things need to happen 1) The MDF file needs to be attached to the Server 2) You are using Integrated Security = True which means the database is using Windows Credentials.  So for more than on user to access the database I usually recommend creating a User Group Account and make the credentials of database the Group Account 3) Since you are accessing the database from a remote machine using Integrated Security = true the User Group Account need to be on both local and remote machines. So you need to put both machines into a Group so they can share a group account.

Comment: I would debug the problem using SQL Server Management Studio from the remote machine.  Once you get SSMS to query the database the c# code should work with no issues.  First connect to the remote Server using Windows Credentials on the SSMS login window.  Then browse to Database and perform a query of the database.  If the database is not attached then you can use SSMS to attach the database.  The mdf file must be on the same machine as the SQL Server.  It can be on the c:\  drive or any drive that is physically located on the machine like d:\.

Comment: okay I am sorry I am new in stackoverflow

Comment: I installed sql express in client machine not the SSMS , do i have to ? and I want the project to work to any client who installed the setup of my project how to do that ?

Comment: A SQL Database has a Server name an instance that is shown on the login window.  So you can either type the server name and instance (servername\instance) in the login window to the remote database.  Or after you login at the top of the explorer is a Connect pulldown so you can connect to the remote server database.  when you open up SQL Server you are really opening SSMS.  There is SQL Express is the same as full version but you do not have all the features (or limited).

Answer (score 1):

To solve these issue :

1-Open port default 1433 in firewall with using TCP.
2-Use this provider to connect like that :

```
Data Source=(server name);Database=(DB Name);User ID=(User) ; Password=(Password);
```